# AWS Lambda - Create Thumbnail

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am using AWS Lambda for creating resized thumbnails. The source is an S3 bucket and the destination is another S3 bucket. I was able to create the lambda function from Amazon CLI. The function is triggered whenever a new image is added to the source bucket. But, the resize/thumbnail creation is not working. I can see some issue in the CloudWatch Console.

The content of the uploaded ZIP package is:

> CreateThumbnail.js, node_modules

---

```
Unable to import module 'CreateThumbnail': Error
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/CreateThumbnail.js:2:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

---

Best regards,
BP

Comment: Did you follow the [Tutorial: Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally able to find the source of the bug. The command used to make the zip file was causing the issue.

The correct command is:
    zip -r CreateThumbnail.zip *